# Jquery $.when blocks code execution and UI updates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are using JQuery in our single page application.
Our boostrapper is the starting point for the app and looks like this:

```
define('homebootstrapper',
    ['jquery', 'config', 'homerouteconfig', 'presenter', 'dataprimer', 'binder'],
    function ($, config, homeRouteConfig, presenter, dataprimer, binder) {
        var
            run = function () {
                $('#busyIndicator').activity(true);

                $.when(dataprimer.fetch())                
                    .done(function () {
                       // $('#busyIndicator').activity(false);
                    });
            };

        return {
            run: run
        };
    });
```

The dataprimer being called looks like this:

```
define('dataprimer',
    ['ko', 'datacontext', 'config'],
    function (ko, datacontext, config) {

        var logger = config.logger,

            fetch = function () {

                return $.Deferred(function (def) {

                    console.log('in deferred');   
                    $.when(LongTimeProcessing())
                    .pipe(function () {                        
                        logger.success('Fetched data');
                    })

                    .fail(function () { def.reject(); })

                    .done(function () { def.resolve(); });

                }).promise();
            };

        return {
            fetch: fetch
        };
    });

function LongTimeProcessing(options) {
    console.log('in when');
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        var results = options;
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var x = i;
            $('#counter').html(x);
        }
        def.resolve(results);
    }).promise();
}
```

The line `$('#busyIndicator').activity(true);`
should display a progress animation based on SVG or VML. This works well, except when using the JQuery $.when

With this sample code we've tried to create a method that will take some time and is called 'LongTimeProcessing' (instead of an ajax call to the backend which is normally used through amplify)

We see that when we use jquery, the busyindicator doesn't work (read: is not displayed) until the dataprimer returns with def.resolve(). This when seems to block all UI updates. Also, the counter value from the LongTimeProcessing method only shows the last value from this loop. It is executed but it is never visible.

What are we doing wrong? How should we handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **MUST** yield to the event processing loop to allow the UI to update and to process outstanding events.  This only happens when your own code has finished executing.

Your `LongTimeProcessing` function does not do this, it starts a loop and doesn't return control to the browser until that loop has finished.

You could achieve what you want by using `setTimeout` to handle the loop iteration:

```
function LongTimeProcessing(options) {
    console.log('in when');
    return $.Deferred(function (def) {
        var results = options;

        var i = 0;

        (function iterate() {
            $('#counter').html(i);
            if (i < 10) {
                ++i;
                setTimeout(iterate, 250);
            } else {
                def.resolve(results);
            }
        })();

    }).promise();
}
```

The call to `setTimeout` allows the function to terminate immediately after the first call to `iterate()`, allowing the browser's event processing loop to process UI updates, and then going into the next iteration when the timer elapses.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. I assume amplify does this by default when making a call to the backend?

Comment: @Thomas no idea, but if the call to the backend uses AJAX then it's implicitly asynchronous.